# InvalidCastException from EventHandler`1 to EventHandler during runtime – but it worked before

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, exception, casting

I'm getting `InvalidCastException` on casting **EventHandler`1** to **EventHandler** in code which worked before and I'm aware of no related changes. (I have both old and new version.)

The funny thing is I'm using the type consistently. **I don't understand why widening of EventHandler`1 to EventHandler even occurs.** Please see attached source excerpts:

The basis is like this:

```vb
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Public Class CapturedEventArgs
    Inherits EventArgs

    Property Handled As Boolean
    Property Processor As clsScannerProcessor
    Property Scan As String
End Class

Public Class clsScannerProcessor

    Public Event CapturedInProcessor As EventHandler(Of CapturedEventArgs)

    'executed in background thread
    Sub EvaluateScan()
        'excerpt: ... on valid scan pattern
        Dim cea As New CapturedEventArgs() With {.Scan = _scan,
                                                 .Processor = Me,
                                                 .Handled = False}
        _mainContext.Send(AddressOf RaiseCapturedInProcessorEvent, cea)  'EXCEPTION HERE
     End Sub

    'executed in main thread
    Private Sub RaiseCapturedInProcessorEvent(e As Object)
        RaiseEvent CapturedInProcessor(Me, DirectCast(e, CapturedEventArgs))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Please do you have any idea why the types are suddenly incompatible at runtime? The code worked before I've made no changes to inherited type.

The thing I added is custom event relay for events of this type. As far as I understand, It should not be related.

Full exception text:

```
System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventHandler`1[myProject.clsScannerProcessor+CapturedEventArgs]' to type 'System.EventHandler'.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
       at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
       at vpsCRMsql.clsScannerProcessor.EvaluateScan() in ...
       at vpsCRMsql.clsScannerProcessor.EvaluateKeystroke(stQueuedEvent keyEvent) in ...
       at vpsCRMsql.clsScannerProcessor.WatchQueue() in ...
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
```

The overall model:

multiple device processors (running in separate threads) raise their own events which go to event relay to raise one common event.

Event relay (in class **clsScannerManager** managing one or more instances of above **clsScannerProcessor**) is like this:

```vb
Public Class clsScannerManager

    Public Custom Event Captured As EventHandler(Of clsScannerProcessor.CapturedEventArgs)
        AddHandler(ByVal value As EventHandler(Of clsScannerProcessor.CapturedEventArgs))
            _eventReceivers.Add(value)
        End AddHandler
        RemoveHandler(value As EventHandler(Of clsScannerProcessor.CapturedEventArgs))
            _eventReceivers.Remove(value)
        End RemoveHandler
        RaiseEvent(sender As Object, e As clsScannerProcessor.CapturedEventArgs)
            For Each handler As EventHandler In _eventReceivers
                'some more complex work in here
            Next
        End RaiseEvent
    End Event

    Sub AddEventToProcessor(processor As clsScannerProcessor)
        AddHandler processor.CapturedInProcessor, AddressOf RaiseCapturedEvent
    End Sub

    Sub RaiseCapturedEvent(sender As Object, e As clsScannerProcessor.CapturedEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Captured(sender, e)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `Captured` event?  That seems to me to be the key.

Comment: @roryap - I added it also with some other things which are potentially important (sorry for long question since the addition was made)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a hunch but should the line that looks like this:

```
For Each handler As EventHandler In _eventReceivers
```

actually look like this

```
For Each handler As EventHandler(Of clsScannerProcessor.CapturedEventArgs) In _eventReceivers
```

and

```
Private _eventReceivers As New ArrayList()
```

should actually look like this:

```
Private _eventReceivers As New List(Of EventHandler(Of clsScannerProcessor.CapturedEventArgs))
```

The exception you are getting is coming from the For Each line. The variable _eventReceivers has a collection of objects in it that are of type EventHandler(Of clsScannerProcessor.CapturedEventArgs), though the references are actually stored as objects. EventHandler(Of clsScannerProcessor.CapturedEventArgs) can't be cast to EventHandler so the cast exception gets thrown. The call through WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send truncates the call stack.

Comment: `Private _eventReceivers As New ArrayList()`. Thank you. The main strange issue still remains without understanding how it is even possible.

Comment: unbelievable, you were right. I'm amazed why I was getting exception at line were you can see comment `'EXCEPTION HERE` (different class etc.). Maybe it can be explained by behavior that exception from the other thread was reported in tricky way at place where execution was leaving the old thread.

Answer (score 0):

**I added this answer for learning purposes.**

The tricky part was the place in the code where exception was thrown in VS 2012:

```
_mainContext.Send(AddressOf RaiseCapturedInProcessorEvent, cea)  'EXCEPTION HERE
```

The actual problem was few levels inside call of `RaiseCapturedInProcessorEvent` (and it was as obvious as shown in accepted answer), but **exception was not shown sooner than at `Send()`**.

The `InvalidCastException` was misleading me into thinking there is problem with `Send()` arguments.